# What is the Google VFE accounts?

Tags: google-apps, user-accounts

What does Google accounts starting with vfe.XXX.* mean? Are they suspended accounts in the domain?﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those accounts were moved from the legacy Postini environment.  They should all be suspended accounts assigned to the "VFE" license type (Vault Former Employee).  Those accounts contain all of your Postini message archive data.